# Storing parameters in a class, and how to access them

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that randomly assembles mathematical expressions using the values stored in this class.
The operators are stored in a dictionary along with the number of arguements they need.
The arguements are stored in a list. (the four x's ensure that the x variable gets chosen often)
depth, ratio, method and riddle are other values needed.

I put these in a class so they'd be in one place, where I can go to change them.
Is this the best pythonic way to do this?
It seems that I can't refer to them by Params.depth. This produces the error 'Params has no attribute 'depth'. I have to create an instance of Params() (p = Params()) and refer to them by p.depth.

I'm faily new to Python. Thanks

```
class Params(object):
    def __init__(self):
        object.__init__(self)
        self.atoms =['1.0','2.0','3.0','4.0','5.0','6.0','7.0','8.0','9.0','x','x','x','x']
        self.operators = {'+': 2, '-': 2, '*': 2, '/': 2,'+': 2, '-': 2, '*': 2, '/': 2, '**': 2, '%': 2}
        self.depth = 1
        self.ratio = .4
        self.method = ''
        self.riddle = '1 + np.sin(x)'
```

Comment: I guess I'll nitpick here and say that `object.__init__` does nothing.

Comment: I learned more from both responses. I'll accept Triptych. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have there are object properties. You mean to use class variables:

```
class Params(object):
    atoms =['1.0','2.0','3.0','4.0','5.0','6.0','7.0','8.0','9.0','x','x','x','x']
    operators = {'+': 2, '-': 2, '*': 2, '/': 2,'+': 2, '-': 2, '*': 2, '/': 2, '**': 2, '%': 2}
    depth = 1
    ratio = .4
    method = ''
    riddle = '1 + np.sin(x)'

# This works fine:
Params.riddle
```

It's fairly common in Python to do this, since pretty much everyone agrees that `Params.riddle` is a lot nicer to type than `Params['riddle']`.  If you find yourself doing this a lot you may want to use [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308/) which makes things a bit easier and much clearer semantically.

*Warning:* if that `Params` class gets too big, an older, grumpier Pythonista may appear and tell you to just move all that crap into its own module.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a class, but I'd prefer to just put it in a dictionary. Dictionaries are the all-purpose container type in Python, and they're great for this sort of thing.

```
params = {
    atoms: ['1.0','2.0','3.0','4.0','5.0','6.0','7.0','8.0','9.0','x','x','x','x'],
    operators: {'+': 2, '-': 2, '*': 2, '/': 2,'+': 2, '-': 2, '*': 2, '/': 2, '**': 2, '%': 2},
    depth: 1,
    ratio: .4,
    method: '',
    riddle = '1 + np.sin(x)'
}
```

Now you can do `params['depth']` or `params['atoms'][2]`. Admittedly, this is slightly more verbose than the object form, but personally I think it's worth it to avoid polluting the namespace with unnecessary class definitions.

Comment: You're "polluting the namespace" with exactly the same number of new global names: 1.